# std::swap(); not working when used in an else statement

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, swap

Here is a set of conditionals which moves a **char** in a vector, using the **swap** function, depending on certain variables:

```cpp
 if (m == 's')
{
  if (currenti == 5)
  {
    swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[0][currentj]);
  }
  else if (height[currenti++][currentj] == 'T')
  {
    cout << "Game over!" << endl;
    gameLive = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti++][currentj]);
  }
}
```

For some reason the **swap** in the **else** part doesn't swap the two vector parts, even though it is called. (I put in a cout, in the **else** section, to check this). However, if I remove the other conditionals like this:

```cpp
if (m == 's')
{
  swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti++][currentj]);
}
```

It works completely fine.

Does anyone know what is causing it to not work in the **"else"** format?

Comment: Odds are the `currenti++` is taking effect AFTER the function runs. Best not to take risks like this.

Comment: currenti is advanced once in else if

Comment: `else if (height[currenti++][currentj] == 'T')` will increment `currenti`, regardless whether you enter the `if()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

> swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti++][currentj]);

This is swapping the same value. current++ is **post-increment**, so its value is only incremented after the line.

I think you mean to do this:

```
swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti+1][currentj]);
```

You probably do want to increment `currenti` after the line above. You could use pre-increment for that:

```
++currenti;
```

There's a slight performance benefit with pre-increment since the value is incremented first, but with post-increment a copy of the original value is used.

Comment: Two points: 1. You don't necessarily know which parameter to `swap` will be evaluated first, so it's possible this could provide the expected results because the parameters are effectively backwards. 2. That `currenti++` probably still has to happen somewhere. I'd drop it in on the line after the `swap`

Comment: @user4581301 I agree that `currenti++` probably needs to happen after the line. However, I leave that decision to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti++][currentj]); // Don't do it!!
```

Is swapping a value with ***itself***! The expression `height[currenti++][current]` takes **current** value of `currenti` as the first index, then increments it.

You should use code like this for your `else` block:

```
else
{
    swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti+1][currentj]);
    ++currenti;
}
```

Note: It is tempting to use the **pre-increment** operator for the index in the second argument:

```
swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[++currenti][currentj]); // Don't do it!!
```

but this is ***undefined behaviour***, as the order of evaluation of the arguments to `std::swap` is unspecified. One or other of the two (post- or pre-increment) **may** work, on *some* platforms, *some* of the time, but you can never rely on it.

Comment: Your closing statement slightly derails the opening statement. Since the order is unspecified (undefined before C++17), it's possible the second parameter is resolved first and `swap(height[currenti][currentj], height[currenti++][currentj]);`  behaves as expected.

Comment: @user4581301 - See edit! Hope this explains the 'slight' derailment issue.

Comment: @user4581301 OK, I now get what you mean! Either way, the recommended code will work safely, in whichever order the arguments are evaluated.

Comment: I thought it *was* undefined behavior to use an auto-increment on a variable that is used in other places in the statement. Did this change?

Comment: @MarkRansom I think you are correct! I have edit my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: cppreference says `f(++i, ++i);       // undefined behavior until C++17, unspecified after C++17`, but it also says *In a function call, value computations and side effects of the initialization of every parameter are indeterminately sequenced with respect to value computations and side effects of any other parameter.* So I think the order of the evaluation is still undefined, but you're guaranteed that each evaluation is complete before proceeding, no matter what the order.